# Dojo and unregistering widgets

Tags: dojo, widget, toolkit

I am new to the Dojo Toolkit. I'm getting the error

```
Tried to register widget with id=myButton but that id is already registered
```

whenever I try to load dojo content twice (meaning I load HTML content through jQuery.Load into a container div). Is there a way of unregistering already registered widgets in dojo? I've seen some examples, but I don't really get them working.

My button:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="myButton">button</button>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're looking to unregister specific widgets, you can use their `destroy()`  or `destroyRecursive()` methods. The second one destroys any widgets inside the one you are destroying (i.e. calling destroyRecursive on a form widget will also destroy all the form components).

In your case, it sounds like your best bet would be to do this before `jQuery.load` -

```
var widgets = dijit.findWidgets(<containerDiv>);
dojo.forEach(widgets, function(w) {
    w.destroyRecursive(true);
});
```

The above code will unregister all widgets in `<containerDiv>`, *and* preserve their associated DOM Nodes. To destroy the DOM nodes, pass `false` to `destroyRecursive` instead.

Reference:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dijit/_Widget/destroyRecursive

Comment: Others looking for a solution : See also answer below for non-recursive solution.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 10):

Based on http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5438, I found a sufficient way of destroying dojo-widgets:

```
dijit.registry.forEach(function(w){
                  w.destroy();             
          });
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
dijit.byId( 'myButton' ).destroy( true );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off removing the id from your button and accessing it using an attach point. You would basically do `<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-attach-point="myButton">button</button>`

then in your code you would access it like `this.myButton....` however im not sure which version of dojo you are using. This will fix any id issues since dojo will assign a unique id to it automatically.