# get all widgets inside an element

Tags: dojo

From the [dojo documents](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/registry) on `dijit.registry`, I see the `forEach` method accepts a last parameter `thisObject`. But it doesn't way what that object is. Is it a dijit widget or a dojo object?

I want to destroy all widgets inside an element (that will be replaced by AJAX) so they can be parsed again without conflicting id's.

```
dijit.registry.forEach(function(w) {
    w.destroyRecursive();
}, dojo.byId("ajaxElement"));
```

But this destroys **ALL** widgets on the page...

Comment: Check this stackoverflow question, it has been answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763983/dojo-and-unregistering-widgets

Answer (score 3):

The `thisObject` is the scope object to invoke the function passed in as the first parameter of `forEach`.

A couple of solutions you can use in this case:

1) Use `dijit.findWidgets` to find all the dijits in a DOM node and destroy them one by one.
dijit.findWidgets returns array of widgets which takes domnode as a parameter
2) `dojo.parser.parse` returns an array of all the dijits that it creates, store that array and destroy the dijits before you call `dijit.parser.parse` again.

3) Use `dijit.registry.filter` to filter out the dijits you want to keep.