# DOJO and DIJIT can not parse same ID twice?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dojo

I am having a problem while working with DOJO where I will dynamically load a div with some content and then run parser.parse(dom.byId("mainDiv")); with the respective requires. And that works beautifully the first time. The second time however I end up running into a problem where it just shows the content no longer activated or styled.

On a second run what I do is remove all the html in the div and then replace the html with basic unparsed text and then I parse it again. Now I am guessing it has to do something with dijit.registry however I can not find exactly what the issue is as I have tried clearing that out as well to no avail. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dojo keeps track of the objects / widgets it creates by the specified id. If you run the parser again on an object with the same id, dojo tries to create a second instance, but there is already one, so it should throw an error in your js console (please check).

You could leave the id blank, then dojo / parse should create an id for you. 
Dojo allows you to find dom elements by class attributes, that way you could pass your div-element to the parse() function without giving it an explicit id.

Anotherway would be to destroy the created widget/object before you parse the div-element again, take a look here for that:

[Dojo and unregistering widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763983/dojo-and-unregistering-widgets)

Quote from http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/parser#parse

> "If you try to parse the same content twice, or parse content
>   mentioning id's of existing widgets, it will cause an exception about
>   duplicate id's"

Comment: Right that I understand however I am wondering how to do "Anotherway would be to destroy the created widget/object"

Comment: i added a link to my original answer for that

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful. It was the word registering that I was missing during my searching haha.

Comment: hahah Thank you very much though this is exactly what I needed.